# Finding lectures PDF "Four lectures on simple groups and singularities"

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

I would be very interested to find the PDF "Four lectures on simple groups and singularities" by Peter Slodowy, especially the lecture 4. I used to print them but lost it. Does anyone has them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a copy of it just by googling the title: I don't know if there are't any copyright issues, nevertheless you can find it [here](https://en.annas-archive.org/md5/39304d4d5759fed23b2a50f404d5c2e5).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delay of accepting the answer.

Comment: Don't worry about it @NicolasHemelsoet. I'm glad to have been of some help.

Answer (score 2):

The notes were produced at the University Utrecht in 1980 as part of the series:
Communications of the Mathematical Institute Rijksuniversiteit Utrecht Nr  11-(1980). I can ask my (=Utrecht) math department if there is still a hard copy left.
Anyhow I have a copy and could try to scan it.

Best regards,

Dirk Siersma
d.siersma "at" uu   dot  nl